# How to remove border from table's cell

Tags: css

I try to remove border from attribute in table but it's not work!
border: none;
border: 0;
please tell me what's I'm wrong? and What should I do?

Thanks.
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jh3EC.png)
[Picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaNU6.png)

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: Try to change `border-box: none`

Comment: I'm a beginner and I try to add function but it's not work

Comment: can You provide JSFIDDLE

Comment: Try tr td {border:none;}

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your

`border-box: 0;`

to

`border-box: none !important;`

**!important** will override if a part of your css below re-edit your border-box. You probably included your css file before your bootstrap / other css lib

Comment: I changed it follow your code but it just removed bottom border in table.

Comment: Try this then : 
 `-webkit-box-shadow: none !important;`
 `-moz-box-shadow: none !important;`
 `box-shadow: none !important;`

Comment: yes, it's not have the shadow on my table but not remove border from my attribute

Comment: Then add `border: none !important;` :)

Comment: Not work but thank so much. I think it's a problem in html but I use CSS from bootstrap I don't know how to edit this.

Answer (score 0):

did you use "table-bordered" class in your HTML, if you used this class remove the class and run it

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
td {
  border: none;
}
```

Hope it'll work.

Comment: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

HTML:

```
<table border="0"></table>
```

CSS:

```
table td, 
table th {
    border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this may be it helps

```
<table border="0"></table> // Add border attribute in table
```

or you can also try with css i.e

```
table tr td,table{
  border:0px;
  box-shadow:none;
  border-color:transparent;         
}
```